# How to Split a Number In Half but not by dividing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I have my program set up so that it takes in names and then splits them until it gets to a number between 1 and 9 so if the number is 35 it would split to add 5 and 3 which gives 8. My problem with my program is that if I ask to enter only 1 name it gives an error but 2 and up names work? What do I do?

```
    import sys


    print("Please enter each name when asked without any spaces.") #The program will post this
    print("Please enter each of your names individually also.")    #Program will again post this




    names = [] #This is the value of names which will be changed depending on the input
    currentnum = 0 #Currentnum value is 0

    while True:
        try:
        num_names = int(input("Enter number of names: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
            print("That's not a number!")



    for i in range(num_names):
    name = input("Enter name " + str(i) + " :")
    name = name.upper()
    while True:
        if name.isalpha():
            break
        else:
               name = input("Enter name number " + str(i) + " again:")
    names.append(name)


    num1 = ["A", "J", "S"]
    num2 = ["B", "K", "T"]
    num3 = ["C", "L", "U"]
    num4 = ["D", "M", "V"]    #This is a dictionary giving all the upper case letters a value of num1, num2 etc
    num5 = ["E", "N", "W"]
    num6 = ["F", "O", "X"]
    num7 = ["G", "P", "Y"]
    num8 = ["H", "Q", "Z"]
    num9 = ["I", "R"]

 def name_value(name):
    return sum((ord(chr) - 65) % 9 + 1 for chr in name])

totalValue = 0
for list_name in names:
    totalValue += name_value(list_name)   

    values = []
    totalCount = 0
    for x in values:                           #This will activate or iterate the loop for the value
        totalCount = totalCount + x     #This will add all the values together and to give a totalcount


    while len(str(totalValue)) != 1:        #The code will split the 2 digit number until the addition equals to 1 digit 
            num = 0 
            for x in str(totalValue):       #This is the value x in the string     totalcount
                num = num + int(x)       #This means that the number being output will have the int of the value x
                totalValue = str(num)    #The totalCount must equal to the string of num

    #[int(d) for d in str(totalValue)]    

    print(totalValue)
```

Comment: Is one name a valid option? If not use an exception handler until > 1 is input.

Comment: You should fix your pasted code here. It is not indented correctly.

Comment: Your code clearly expects at least 2 names: second_name = list_names[1], so you will need to validate that input first. Please try debugging you logic and inspecting values on the line before your code fails.

Answer (score 0):

**IMMEDIATE PROBLEM**

In your lines below, you require at least two names:

```
list_names = list(names)

first_name = list_names[0]
second_name = list_names[1]
#third_name = list_names[2]
```

If there's no second name, that **second_name** assignment fails.  I can't help much more, since you haven't described what your program is supposed to do, nor have you focused in on the actual problem point.

**SOLUTION**

You need to cycle through however many names you have in your overall list.  Don't hard-code **first_name**, **second_name**, etc.  Instead, use something like this:

```
for name in list_names:
    for chr in name:
        ... the part you already know how to do ...
```

**MORE UPGRADES**

Your value translation also needs to be generalized.  Instead of these three-letter lists, use a dictionary that translates each letter to a value:

```
score = {
    'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C':3, ...
}
```

Now, you can get the letter value simply with

```
totalValue += score[chr]
```

After this, look up the concept of a *list comprehension* and use the **sum** method on a list of scores.  If you learn these, you can compute the value of each name in a single line of code, much more readable than your current implementation.

Comment: So basically I want to have the program so that it works with 1 word because at the moment it does not. So I belive it is something to do with the first_name second_name so what do I do because I need the program to take in from 1 to as many names as possible. But of course it needs the second name so what do I do not force it to have at least two names and only have it to at least have 1 name?

Comment: I have also realised that it does not work with 3 it only works with 2 as for third_name it is hashed out so basically how would I get it so there is no set amount of words needed

Comment: Basically look up to the other answer and thats how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this code before... you may want tell is what problem you are actually trying to solve instead of what you think will make it work.

You can replace most of your long `if/else`s with:

```
def name_value(name):
    return sum((ord(chr) - 65) % 9 + 1 for chr in name])

totalValue = 0
for list_name in names:
    totalValue += name_value(list_name)
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
num1 = ["A", "J", "S"]
num2 = ["B", "K", "T"]
num3 = ["C", "L", "U"]
num4 = ["D", "M", "V"]    #This is a dictionary giving all the upper case letters a value of num1, num2 etc
num5 = ["E", "N", "W"]
num6 = ["F", "O", "X"]
num7 = ["G", "P", "Y"]
num8 = ["H", "Q", "Z"]
num9 = ["I", "R"]

list_names = list(names)

first_name = list_names[0]
second_name = list_names[1]
#third_name = list_names[2]

for chr in first_name:      #if, elif and else code
        if (chr in num1):
                totalValue += 1
        elif (chr in num2):
                totalValue += 2
        elif (chr in num3):
                totalValue += 3
        elif (chr in num4): 
                totalValue += 4       #This gives TotalValue(the number answer) depending on the letter
        elif (chr in num5): 
                totalValue += 5
        elif (chr in num6): 
                totalValue += 6
        elif (chr in num7):
                totalValue += 7
        elif (chr in num8):
                totalValue += 8
        elif (chr in num9):
                totalValue += 9
    else:
            print("program failure")


for chr in second_name:      #if, elif and else code
    if (chr in num1):
            totalValue += 1
    elif (chr in num2):
            totalValue += 2
    elif (chr in num3):
            totalValue += 3
    elif (chr in num4): 
            totalValue += 4       #This gives TotalValue(the number answer) depending on the letter
    elif (chr in num5): 
            totalValue += 5
    elif (chr in num6): 
            totalValue += 6
    elif (chr in num7):
            totalValue += 7
    elif (chr in num8):
            totalValue += 8
    elif (chr in num9):
            totalValue += 9
    else:
            print("You have entered invalid inputs for names. Program will Now end.")
```

Let the computer do the math for you.

Comment: TemporalWolf I did this and it fixed but now its not working again and giving me values of 0 I think I broke the system because it went to a three digit number eg 353 and it couldnt split

Comment: @StackOverflowUser Update your question with your revised code.

Comment: Ok I will it worked for a while then boom all of a sudden I started getting the value 0